# object consisting of jQuery element

Tags: jquery, object, storing-data

#### current code

I've built function to do something over collection of jQuery elements:

```
var collection = $([]); //empty collection
```

I add them with:

```
collection = collection.add(e);
```

and remove with:

```
collection = collection.not(e);
```

It's pretty straightforward solution, works nicely.

#### problem

Now, I would like to have an object consisting of various settings set to any jQuery element, i.e.:

```
function addObject(e){
  var o = {
    alpha: .6 //float
    base: {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255} //color object
  }

  e.data('settings', o);
}
```

But when I pass jQuery object/element to function (i.e. as `e`), calling `e.data` doesn't work, although it would be simplest and really nice solution.

#### question

If I have an "collection" of jQuery elements, what is the simplest way of storing some data for each element of set?

Comment: I had no idea you could create and use a collection as you have noted. Thats is such piece of gold. Thanks!

Comment: @prodigitalson: I'll probably have to blog about it, although I don't think it's that unique idea... is it? :]

Comment: Well perhaps um just "uncreative" but i never though to pass an empty array/object to jQ to get a naked collection backed by it. I would always use an array/object and then `$.each` over it which of course implies a lot of other things in the implementation :-)

Comment: I still go over this `collection` via `$.each`, however, control of what is in that collection is dead-simple.

Comment: @Adam Kiss: Negative.  I'm interested.

Comment: @adam: Re:collection and `$.each` - Yeah but my main point is you have standard ways yo search/add/remove items from the collection without creating an entirely new prototype (add, not, filter, find?).

Comment: @prodigitalson, @justkt: I hear ya. http://adam.kissyour.net/11-using-empty-set-with-jquery-part-1 @prodigitalson: Read that blogpost, and you'll see why I used this construction. Or better, maybe you'll show me better way :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, solved it already :)

#### last version:

This is somewhat simplified code:

```
function setData(e,key,data){
  if(typeof(e)==string){ e = $(e); }

   $(e).data(key,data);
}
```

#### solution

Problem was, that I wanted to keep myself option to add element via `$('element')`, `'element'`, or `$(this)`, so I had to add `typeof` check before setting data - the same way jQuery works.

if I'm adding element as **selector only**, it's `$(e)`, if I'm adding **jQuery object**, it's `e`:

```
function setData(e,key,data){
  if(typeof(e)==string){
    $(e).data(key,data);
  }else{
    e.data(key,data);
  }
}
```

So you all get upvote, and I'll pick myself as a winner in two days, so anyone who will stumble upon this question will know what to do (clearly, tested, works :]) and why :)

**Edit**: note: This probably isn't final version - I have read more documentation, so this `setData` function supports all types which `jQuery.add` supports.

Comment: So then nodes added to your collection were in fact wrapped in jQuery?

Comment: some yes - already, some not. That is the point of that `typeof` check - to decide, which are already wrapped and which not :]

Answer (score 2):

If those "elements" are actual DOM elements (nodes), then can't you just use `$(e).data(...)`?

Comment: Pointy: that was one of my problems - `add` supports three or four ways how to describe what you want to add, so you have to check which type you actually do add

Answer (score 1):

I think the problwm ia when youre dealing with a collection in this fashion and you add an item... if it hasnt been wrapped with jquery yet it wont be. Thus, when accessed again its simply the raw element.

If i am correct in this line of thinking an `e` is infact a dom element/node (or its string representation) then a simple `$(e)` should give you access to its `data` method.

```
function addObject(e){
  var o = {
    alpha: .6 //float
    base: {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255} //color object
  }

  $(e).data('settings', o);
}
```

Comment: this way, if I `addObject ($(this))`, it will fail... so I have to check check check :]

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you've missed a comma between your two properties?

```
  var o = {
    alpha: .6 <-- here 
    base: {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255} 
  }
```

(I doubt it, but felt the need to point it out)

This works, and is somewhat neater (IMO at least):

```
    $.fn.addObject = function(){
        var o = {
            alpha: .6, //float
            base: {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255} //color object
        }
         $(this).data('settings', o);
    };

    // simple test
    $("div").addObject();
    alert($("div").data("settings").alpha); // alerts 0.6
```

Comment: karim79: great idea, unfortunately, adding that object is just one part of greater "plugin", so this is too "dirty" for me :] thank you for your try, however :]